# Curl: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: python, flask, curl

I am trying to build the digit recognition app found in this tutorial:

https://www.toptal.com/data-science/machine-learning-number-recognition

https://github.com/teimurjan/digits-recognizer

I run the app.py file and it shows this in the terminal:

```
(virtualenv) PS C:\Users\alexm\PycharmProjects\digit_recognition> py -m  flask run
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
```

Then I run the provided command in the CMD terminal on windows:

`curl "http://localhost:5000/api/predict" -X "POST" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"image\": \"data:image/png;base64,$(curl "https://media.istockphoto.com/vectors/number-eight-8-hand-drawn-with-dry-brush-vector-id484207302?k=6&m=484207302&s=170667a&w=0&h=s3YANDyuLS8u2so-uJbMA2uW6fYyyRkabc1a6OTq7iI=" | base64)\"}" -i`

I get this error and no other information:

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: That means your CMD terminal can't find `curl`. It's not a problem with how you're _using_ curl, it's a problem with having curl (correctly) _installed at all in the first place_. I'd focus on trying to get to where `curl --version` works before trying to do anything else.

Comment: That said, `$(curl ...)` is a UNIX-ism; it's not expected to work in cmd.exe (in addition to being a bad way to do things in UNIX and not recommended there either), so you _will_ have more problems to fix after you've fixed that first one.

Comment: ...have you considered using a powershell script instead of using cmd at all? IIRC, powershell has native JSON parsing and generation support, so you should be able to avoid the need to try to generate JSON with string concatenation in the first place.

Comment: ...IIRC, powershell _also_ has native HTTP support, so using powershell properly can also stop you from needing to use `curl` in the first place as well.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I was able to successfully use curl commands when building a toy API (https://mattermost.com/blog/how-to-build-a-basic-api-with-python-flask/) so I am guessing that curl is installed? I have not tried a powershell script. This is all pretty new to me so don't know how to deviate much from what is provided in the tutorial. What would this command look like as a powershell script?

Comment: Sorry -- my closest-to-relevant expertise is bash, not cmd or powershell; I've done a little powershell here or there when pressed (mostly during CTF exercises), but I'm not the right person to go into detail on it.